# Does field delimiter matter in binary file formats in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

In `textfile` format, data is stored in text format with fields delimited by field delimiter. That's why we prefer non-readable delimiter like *CTRL^A*.

But is there any effect of using field delimiter while creating hive table in `rcfile`, `orc`, `avro` & `sequencefile`.

In some hive tutorials, I saw usage of delimiter in these binary file formats too.

Example:

`create table olympic_orcfile(athelete STRING,age INT,country STRING,year STRING,closing STRING,sport STRING,gold INT,silver INT,bronze INT,total INT) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as orcfile;`

Does field delimiter ignored or it matter in binary file formats in Hive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignored by RCFILE, ORC and AVRO but does matter for SEQUENCEFILE.